In a RISC-V architecture, do jump instructions (conditional or JAL/JALR) increase the PC by 4 as the rest of the instructions?
I'm working on a RISC-V CPU emulator and have all instructions implemented. The thing is that I'm not sure if the jumps are failing. This is the current implementation I have for BGEU to make an example:
void CPU::BGEU() {
uint8_t rs1 = instDecoded.registers[0];
uint8_t rs2 = instDecoded.registers[1];
uint32_t inmediate = instDecoded.inmediate;

if (static_cast<uint32_t>(registers[rs1]) >= static_cast<uint32_t>(registers[rs2])) 
    pc += inmediate;
}

I have another method called "clock" which executes the instruction and then add 4 to PC, but I don't know if after a jump I should add 4.

JMP changes the PC to a new value. No sense in incrementing it as well. I once worked with a (16-bit) CPU that did that and we had to write JMP label-2. It was ridiculous.

If processors internally increment by 4 before then setting to new value, who is to say as this cannot be externally seen. Thus, this is an implementation detail that can vary across processors.

@ErikEidt But it's usually implemented after the instruction has been executed, right? That's how I have it implemented, so it does affect if I increment the PC.

@user207421 Yeah, I know, but do you know if it's specified in any official RISC-V document? Because I haven't found anything.

The execution of JAL(R) and Branch instructions is well specified.  There is no doubt about +/-4, so just do exactly what the specifications say.  If the processor wants to +4 internally, either before or after otherwise setting the new pc, that's its own internal business; it will have to account for that so as to meet the architectural specification.

Control Transfer Instructions
In the RISC-V architecture, control transfer instructions, which include the unconditional jumps and conditional branches, manipulate the program counter (PC) differently compared to regular instructions. While most instructions simply advance the PC by 4 bytes, control transfer instructions adjust the PC based on specific conditions or targets.
1. Unconditional jumps
In such operations, the PC is supposed to jump to a specific target address.
Example: JAL (Jump and Link), JALR (Jump and Link Register)
JAL
Directly jumps to a computed address derived from the current PC added to an immediate offset (of J-type encoding). It stores the address of the next sequential instruction (PC + 4) into register rd.
target address = PC + immediate offset
JALR
Jumps to an address calculated by adding a base register value (rs1) to a 12-bit immediate offset (of I-type encoding), then setting the least significant bit of this result to 0 to align with the 2-byte boundary (for the compressed instruction set). Similar to JAL, it stores the next instruction's address in register rd.
target address = (rs1 + immediate offset) & ~1
2. Conditional Branches
Example: BEQ (branch equality),BNE (branch inequality), BLT[U] (branch less than or equality, where U is added for unsigned), BGE[U] (branch greater than or equality, where U is added for unsigned))
Behavior:

If the condition is satisfied, the PC is set to current PC + immediate offset, where immediate is a signed offset (of B-type encoding) determining the jump length.
If the condition is not met, the PC advances by 4 i.e. PC + 4 to execute the next sequential instruction.

Clock
Purpose: The clock in a CPU emulator synchronizes the sequence of operations, ensuring accurate timing and control over the instruction execution cycle.
Design Implementation: Each instruction type should handle its PC adjustments to respect their unique requirements in logic. This modular approach ensures clarity and reduces errors in emulation, especially around the handling of the PC.
Therefore, all of the instructions defined should handle the calculation of target address individually instead of being handled by the clock method universally.
Conclusion
Hence, to summarize the recommended corrections:

Implement individual logic for PC adjustment directly within each instruction's method. The clock method should not automatically increment the PC; instead, allow each instruction to manage the PC based on its operational logic.
Calculate the branch target by adjusting the PC to "current PC + immediate" if the branch condition is true, where the immediate is the decoded offset from the instruction format. If the branch condition is false, then the PC should simply advance to the next instruction (PC + 4).


Let's also note that "The jump and link (JAL) instruction uses the J-type format, where the J-immediate encodes a signed
offset in multiples of 2 bytes — so the J-immediate is shifted by 1 (multiplied by 2).  This doubling also applies to BEQ (but not JALR).

"then setting the least significant bit of this result to 0 to align with the 4-byte boundary" — 2 byte boundary; this is to allow for the compressed instruction set without significant tooling change and with binary compatibility.
